# Using Pandas data frame how to randomly select row data using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a data set with column NDVI , Lat , Long, Group, Village & Taluka.

I want to randomly select 10 villages in each taluka,and each 10 villages select 5 row data randomly. but I am stuck to select random function. So, In taluka(block) I want to select 50 Data values, but there is condition is select 10 villages and each village atleast want 5 entries, and based on "Group" column, Probability to Proportion probability select 5 points. If Village XYZ have 70% area in Very Poor" then it will be select n=5 *0.70 = 3.5 Sample = 4(rounding), so it will be 4 data rows will be select for that village. If village XYZ have 30% area in Group: "Good", then it will be randomly select n=5*0.30 =1.5 = 2 (rounding)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel("/home/desktop/Music/Data-Balaghat.xlsx")
def f(x):
    x['No.of Points'] = x.groupby(['Village'])['NDVI'].transform('count')
    x['No.of Points'] = x['No.of Points'].fillna('')
    return x

df1 = df.groupby(['Taluka','Group']).apply(f)
df1 = df.groupby(['Taluka','Village']).apply(f)
sample=df1.loc[df1['No.of Points'] >= 5]
def f(x):
    labels = ['Very Poor','Poor','Average','Good']
    x = x.sort_values('Village','NDVI', ascending=False)
    x['Level'] = pd.qcut(x['NDVI'], 4, labels = labels)
    x['Sum_Level_wise'] = x.groupby(['Village','Level'])['NDVI'].transform('sum')
    x['Probability'] = x['Sum_Level_wise'].div(x['NDVI'].sum()).round(2)
    x['Sample'] = x['Probability'] * x.groupby('Level')['NDVI'].transform('size')
    x['Selected villages'] = x['Sample'].apply(np.ceil).astype(int)
    x['Selected village'] = x.groupby('Level').apply(lambda x: x['Village'].head(x['Selected villages'].iat[0])).reset_index(level=0)['Village']
    x['Selected village'] = x['Selected village'].fillna('')
    return x

df1 = df.groupby(['Taluka','Village']).apply(f)
df1['Selected village'].replace('', pd.np.nan, inplace=True)
df1.dropna(subset=['Selected village'], inplace=True)
```

[image: Data set]

Answer (score 1):

It is a multiple step process.

First i would like to share you these documentations :

pandas.DataFrame.sample:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html

and

random.choice(seq) : https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

It should fit your sampling issue.

Then to decompose your issue.

> I want to randomly select 10 villages in each taluka

Get the unique list of villages in each taluka, creating subsets looping over taluka values.  Once you get the unique list apply random.choice for each list to get your selected village value.

Create a new DataFrame with only selected values for more visibility, not needed for process.

> and each 10 villages select 5 row data randomly

Loop over talukas and selected unique villages, and apply pandas.DataFrame.sample, to select 5 rows each time.

One again save a new DataFrame for visibility

> If Village XYZ have 70% area in Very Poor" then it will be select n=5 *0.70 = 3.5 Sample = 4(rounding), so it will be 4 data rows will be select for that village. If village XYZ have 30% area in Group: "Good", then it will be randomly select n=5*0.30 =1.5 = 2 (rounding)

Here it's all about rules, juste compute you needed indicator in a new column of the dataframe.

Based on your computed indicator value, run again the pandas.DataFrame.sample function with the right n (you can add it in your DataFrame too, it is all up to you, and your will to keep track).